# Jenkins Slave running on Windows 2008 servers Troubleshooting Connection time out

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins but am trying to set up a Jenkins slave.

My Master on a Windows server, Server A does not connect to my Slave, Windows Server B.

So far I continue to receive a

```
Connection time out: connect
Failing to obtain http://server.a.ip:8080/computer/slave/slave-agent.jnlp
```

So far I have:

Global Security - Created an anonymous user with Agent Connect and Read rights

Global Security - Enable security TCP port for JNLP agents as Random

Configuration System - Jenkins URL is http://server.a.ip:8080/

Netstat on Server B shows (while running the java download. Please note that I am able to FTP from each server) -

```
TCP    ServerA IP Address:50081    ServerA:8080         SYN_SENT
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: After opening up both ports 8080 and setting my Fixed port on my Jenkins Configure Global Security in this case 49187 on Server A. I was able to connect into my Jenkins app from server B!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps.

1 -Access Jenkins URL

2 - Go to Manager page.

3 - Manager node.

4 - New node

5 - Choose 'Launch agent via Java Web Start' in launch. Save the new config.

6 - Open Jenkins url in server B and login

7 - Go to Manage Jenkins >> Manage Node

8 - Click in the node name you created then in Launch. And every think is done.

See [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows?focusedCommentId=59510810) for more details.

You need java and login with administrative account in server B

Comment: Thanks Joao, does also mean I would have export the master's installation to keep my credentials and projects onto the Server B?

It seemed unresourceful to have a copy of the full Jenkins installation in every server i have would have a slave running in but I might just be going about this incorrectly

Comment: No, just do as i said. Is like a web installer.

Comment: Would you happen to have experience in giving the http://localhost:8080/computer/Dobby/slave-agent.jnlp link rights to be read on Server B?

Comment: I updated my question now that have a little more knowledge of how slaves work.